# Delay in DTLS handshake between Bouncy Castle client and Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc, bouncycastle, dtls

I am trying to create a DTLS connection between a custom Bouncy Castle based client and Chrome for streaming WebRTC.

The connection succeeds but it takes > 2 seconds to complete.

I looked at a wireshark dump of the connection and here is what it looks like:

[image]

Notice that Chrome sends out multiple server hellos. And these are sent almost one after the other. So this is not a retransmission. And there are the back and forth of Change Cipher Spec messages.
Chrome also sends multiple Change Cipher Spec one after the other.

Any pointers on why the multiple server hellos would be much appreciated. Or a pointer on why there is the two second delay.

Comment: You might want to ask in the Jitsi forums at https://community.jitsi.org/
The Jitsi videobridge uses BouncyCastle to talk DTLS to Chrome so folks should be familiar with the problem

Comment: In the case of captures, a picture tells you 1000 times less than the capture itself ;-). if you have large certificates, that may cause fragmented handshake messages. And may be wireshark shows you rather 3 fragments (when assembled, the flight of messages) then really 3 flights.